# Using ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush when data are maintained in a service

Tags: angular

I'm currently working on an angular application (a text based game) and I'd like to use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` to ensure that the application is reactive/performant. Even though I understand the idea of change detection and immutable, I have difficulties to apply it for my architecture.

Basically, the app is connected to the back end through a web socket connection (via signalR). Therefore, I created different services that are responsible for data. For example, I have a `HangarService` that contains a private member called `_hangars` that contains information about the player's hangar and an accessor (`hangars`) that returns this array. Moreover, I have routing configuration that loads the component `HangarPageComponent`. This component is basically doing this:

```
<hangar *ngFor="let hangar of hangarService.hangars" [data]="hangar"></hangar>
```

So that's how the page is currently displaying all the player's hangar.

Another important thing is that these services can alter the data they maintain. Indeed, let's say that the player makes a move on the map, I have to recaculate the distance between him and all hangars. To do this, when the player moved, the back end send a message through the web socket that is intercepted by the service that will change the `distance` property of ALL the hangars.

I had the opportunity to test the application on a slow computer and it seems that the page is lagging a bit, therefore, I'd like to use `OnPush` strategy. I read a lot on the subject however, I don't really understand how to apply it in my case. Indeed, my first problem is that the `HangarPageComponent` has no input and is not referenced declaratively, it's just instanciated via the router, so I can't really pass input to it, so if I set in on `OnPush` mode, it won't detect updates.

I also tried to create and `@Input` variable that I defined on an `Observable` in `ngOnInit` and I'm using the `async` pipe in my `*ngFor`. If I emit on the `Observable` at every changes at the array level (addition or deletion of items), it works. However, if a property of one of the array items changes, it will be reflected only if `HangarComponent` is not set on "OnPush" (which I'd like as well).

So basically, the question is "how can I use `OnPush` changes strategy when the data are maintained/updated by a service without user interaction" (indeed, hangars data can be modified because a delivery arrived in it, which is triggered by a cron job that sends a signal via the web socket).